# angular input checkbox remove field

Tags: angularjs, forms, checkbox, input

I'm fighting with angular input checkboxes.  I have a simple input that looks like this...

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedExercise.isTimed"   required/>
```

However, when I uncheck the box it removes the .isTimed field from my object, when I want to set it equal to false.  For example...

checked

```
{
  "name": "Work",
  "isTimed": true,
  "duration": 3,
}
```

unchecked

```
{
  "name": "Work",
  "duration": 3,
}
```

I have hacked this to work by adding an ng-change function, but it is super hack in that it just checks to see if angular removed the field, then re-adds it.  Is there a proper way to setup my input checkbox so angular won't remove the object field when the box is unchecked?

Comment: this is because of the `required`.

Comment: @MamaWalter  Thank you!  If you post this as an answer I'll send all the karma to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. You can solve it just by deleting **"required"** in checkbox. As I understand it's just

Comment: It looks like you forgot to finish your answer.

Comment: This is correct.  MamaWalter answered this in the comments to my OP, but he didn't post it as an answer so I will accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with the way that checkboxes are processed.  They tend to only return a value when they are true.  However, with angular you can override this and capture either state.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedExercise.isTimed" ng-true-value="yep" ng-false-value="nope"   required/>
```

Comment: I had already tried something similar.  Adding... ng-false-value="false" ng-true-value="true"  ...has no effect (the field still disappears when I uncheck).    Even if I do something like.....  ng-false-value="'nope" ng-true-value="'yep'"   ... the check value become 'yep' but the field disappears when unchecked.